# object.__init__() takes no parameters

Tags: python, python-3.x, abstract-class

```
import abc

class AbsBaseClass(abc.ABC):
    def __init__(self,x):
        self.x=x

class DerivedClass(AbsBaseClass):
    def __init__(self,y):
        super(AbsBaseClass,self).__init__(y)


ob=DerivedClass(5)
```

Comment: Why are you passing `AbsBaseClass` to `super`? Pass `DerivedClass`, but in Python 3, you can just do: `super().__init__(y)`

Comment: explain yourself better, your question is not clear.

Comment: Your question is all code, wheres your explanation, wheres the desired output, wheres your current error trace-back...

Answer (score 4):

The error is here:

```
class DerivedClass(AbsBaseClass):
    def __init__(self,y):
        super(AbsBaseClass,self).__init__(y)
 #            ^^^^^^^^^^^^ This should be DerivedClass, not AbsBaseClasee
```

Answer (score 0):

Additional, to @NPE's answer.

- you're doing a class as super which is the metaclass, so then if you want that, why not have an empty `super`?
- That's all really :-)...

So code becomes:

```
import abc

class AbsBaseClass(abc.ABC):
    def __init__(self,x):
        self.x=x

class DerivedClass(AbsBaseClass):
    def __init__(self,y):
        super(DerivedClass,self).__init__(y) #!!!


ob=DerivedClass(5)
```

So instead of:

```
super(AbsBaseClass,self).__init__(y)
```

Do:

```
super(DerivedClass,self).__init__(y)
```